# Python AWS CDK Unable to synthetize stack, Unable to set secret rotation in aws cdk

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I've been unable to synth my cdk stack. I need to instantiate a Postgres RDS database instance.  I've attempted to add a single user and secrete rotation schedule to no avail. Do you have any ideas of what is required to achieve a secret rotation? The error message received when trying to synth the stack:

`[Error at /usecase-1-stack/test-uc1-pgdb/Secret/Resource] AwsSolutions-SMG4: The secret does not have automatic rotation scheduled. AWS Secrets Manager can be configured to automatically rotate the secret for a secured service or database.`

and cdk code below:

```
    from aws_cdk import aws_rds as rds
    from aws_cdk import aws_secretsmanager as sm
    from aws_cdk import aws_ec2 as ec2

    curated_rds = rds.DatabaseInstance(
        self,
        f"{env_id}-uc1-pgdb", 
        database_name=curated_db_name,
        engine=rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres(
            version=rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_14_10
        ),
        port=curated_db_port,
        instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
            ec2.InstanceClass.STANDARD5, ec2.InstanceSize.LARGE
        ),
        credentials=rds.Credentials.from_generated_secret(
            "admin",
            encryption_key=data_key,
            secret_name=f"{env_id}-uc1-pgdb-admin",
        ),
        vpc=data_vpc,
        vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
            subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
        ),
        security_groups=[curated_rds_security_group],
        storage_encrypted=True,
        storage_encryption_key=data_key,
        auto_minor_version_upgrade=True,
        deletion_protection=True,
        multi_az=True,
        publicly_accessible=False,
        enable_performance_insights=True,
    )


    # curated_rds.add_rotation_single_user(automatically_after=Duration.days(30))
    curated_rds.secret.add_rotation_schedule("RotationSchedule",  hosted_rotation=sm.HostedRotation.postgre_sql_single_user(), automatically_after=Duration.days(7))
```

Comment: Provide more context - where is that error coming from? Is it some static security analysis? Show your attempts to enable secret rotation and where it went wrong

Comment: the error is coming after running the cdk synth command in the terminal. I'm unable to synthesize the stack. 

All my attempts are in the last two lines of code as these suit our requirements for secrets rotation.  Neither of them seems to pass synth error and I'm unsure why given that adding an automatic rotation to the database is secret.  Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a [cdk-nag](https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-nag/blob/main/RULES.md) error message.

Comment: @fedonev Thank you as I did not catch that initially. I'm still new to cdk and aws. However, I was concerned no actual secret was being rotated hence my answer /query.  I've also managed to implement nag suppression to some strict lambda runtime nags so really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cdk-nag error resulted from a [bug](https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-nag/issues/1565).

The secrets rotation was set but non-compliant even if rotation is configured. I was working under version v2.116 for aws-cdk-lib, and updating to 2.129.0 resolved the issue SMG4.